# Install Sdkman in an Alpine based Docker Image

Tags: docker, alpine-linux, sdkman

I need to install Sdkman in an Alpine based docker image, but there is a problem that default shell is not Bash.  Then command:

```
source "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"
```

ends with failure:

```
/bin/sh: /root/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh: line 40: SDKMAN_PLATFORM+=64: not found
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll need to split the install of SDKMAN and running the init script into two RUN blocks e.g.

```
RUN apk add bash curl git zip && \
  curl -s "https://get.sdkman.io" | bash
RUN bash -c "source $HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh && sdk version"
```

Source: https://e.printstacktrace.blog/using-sdkman-as-a-docker-image-for-jenkins-pipeline-a-step-by-step-guide/

Comment: You can remove the "git" package if you don't need it for some other reason. The documentation states "You need a basic toolchain including bash, zip, unzip, and curl (tar and gzip required for special cases)". Git is a third option for Windows users. See https://sdkman.io/install.